# Handling UTC time within C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, date

I am not an expert on the internals of C# so this question might actually be downright silly. If so, please correct me. I have some data (in UTC format) taken out from a SQL server.

```
2011-03-26 11:03:58.000
2011-03-26 11:04:25.000
...
```

I am parsing this file inside C# and am using the following:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value);
```

to fetch the value into the `DateTime`object. Now, I am subtracting some arbitrary time 6 hours from this time as follows:

```
date = date.Subtract(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0));
```

And finally, I am writing this back into another file as follows:

```
output.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Because I have not done any implicit conversions, the output is also UTC. My question is, is this kind of addition/subtraction of time allowed on the parsed date or do I need to do some UTC to C# specific conversion before being able to manipulate time? I am having difficulties wrapping my head around this. Would someone please clarify this?

**EDIT: Attempt to write a concise question**
The original date is in UTC. I want to add/subtract some time and write it back in UTC. I want to know if I can manipulate the parsed date directly or I need to do some conversions i.e. tell C# explicitly that the date is in UTC format and then manipulate it and then tell it again to write back UTC date.

Comment: Just one small, unrelated hint: You can use `TimeSpan.FromHours(8)` to make the code more readable. There is also FromSeconds, FromMinutes etc.

Comment: Huh? I don't see your problem.

Comment: @SLaks: I've made an attempt to add a more concise question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.  A date is a date, no matter what time zone it's in.  Unless you're converting it to a different time zone, .Net doesn't know or care what time zone it is.

If you want to, you can call `DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc)`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to parse datetimes from SQL Server. The ADO.Net will return a [`SqlDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx) object for a [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type column in a result. ORM libraries (LinqToSQL, Entity Framework etc) are also perfectly capable of mapping `datetime` type columns to [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) properties. If you find yourself parsing a string, you're doing it wrong (not to mention all the implications of [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)...)

As a note the operation you described can be performed straight on the server, eg. add one hour to an UTC datetime field and save it back as UTC datetime:

```
UPDATE table SET column = DATEADD(hour, 1, column) WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the original date the UTC time, or your local time?  If the original is local time and you are subtracting 8 hours to make it UTC, then use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx).  To go the other way, use [DateTime.ToLocalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: The original date is in UTC as well. My mistake, that 8 hours was just an arbitrary number that I am subtracting and has nothing to do with me trying to convert it into UTC.

Comment: In that case, you can to whatever you like with it.  DateTime has methods for adding specific date parts too, like DateTime.AddHours().  The full list is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members(v=vs.71).aspx.  To subtract hours, just add a negative number.

Comment: After reviewing your edit, I suspect that what you are really asking is "Does the .NET DateTime class have some internal notion of whether it represents UTC or some other time zone", in which case the answer is no it does not.

Comment: It Depends. For example, try:Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Kind);  // Local
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.Kind);  // Utc

Comment: True- forgot about Kind.  But that is just UTC or local- I don't think it applies to the specific problem at hand.  It would make a difference if he were to use my first suggestion though, ToUniversalTime or ToLocalTime.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

With the input string being universal, you can use an overload of `DateTime.Parse` that accepts a `DateTimeStyle` to indicate this.

```
string utcDateString = "2011-03-26 11:03:58.000";

DateTime localDate = DateTime.Parse(utcDateString, 
                          CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                          DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

DateTime utcDate = localDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

In this snippet, `localDate` would be the *local time* of the universal time input. So for EDT (US), it would be 7:03:58 AM. `utcDate` would have `11:03:58`, matching the input string.